# Functions - proving injectivity or surjectivity

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Consider a function h: $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z \rightarrow \Bbb Q$ defined as $\displaystyle h(m,n) = \frac{m}{|n|+1}$ Determine whether this is injective and whether it is surjective.

Since this function contains modulus in denominator that means for two elements in the domain there is same image in co domain . Therefore this function is not injective ( one to one).

Please guide how to prove surjectivity for this function....

Comment: This is your $8^{th}$ question here and you've accepted no answers so far. Please consider accepting your favourite answer to questions in which you got at least one satisfying answer.

Comment: Saying it's not injective because of the absolute value in the denominator sounds like you suspect it's not injective but can't really prove it. Can you prove it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right with the injectivity.
The function is surjective:
Let $p,q\in\mathbb Z,p/q\in\mathbb Q$. We can assume $q>0$. Then we have $\displaystyle h(p, q - 1)=\frac p {|q - 1| + 1}=\frac p q$. As we chose $\displaystyle\frac p q$ freely, this shows $h(\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z)=\mathbb Q$.

Comment: why we should consider $q > 0$

Comment: @sultan Do you mean to ask why **can** we consider $q>0$?

Comment: For any element $\frac p q\in\mathbb Q$ we can assume that the denominator $q$ is greater than zero without loss of generality.